# Is this the correct integral for finding the volume of the region bounded by the planes $= 3,=,= 1,= 1,$ and $ = 2$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, iterated-integrals

The integral I've formed here is: $$\int_1^2 \int_0^1 \int^{3y}_y 1 dzdydx$$

Which evaluates to one. Not sure if I'm thinking of the region correctly, does this integral make sense for this region?

Also, a very similar question: Find the volume of the region in the first octant bounded by the coordinate planes and the surface $++= 2$. Would the integral for this region be $$\int_0^2 \int_0^2 \int^{x+y-2}_0 1 dzdydx?$$

I feel as though if I've got just one of those right then I got both right, because I used the same thinking...any help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you get that $y$ is bounded below by $0$?

Comment: @saulspatz Because the lines $z=3y,z=y$ intersect at $y=0$!

Comment: @saulspatz yep what almagest said, I saw that the only solution to $3y =y$ was $y=0$. (I'm guessing you asked this not because you didn't know but because you were checking whether I knew. Thank you!)

Comment: No, I was asking because I didn't see it.  Early in the morning here.

Comment: The short answer is yes. The first integral is fine. You can check by noting that the volume is a triangular prism. The base has area 1 (take side with $y=1$ and then height is 1) and the height of the prism is 1 (from $x=1$ to $x=2$).

Comment: But the second is not quite right. You need a different upper limit for the $y$ integral.

Comment: @almagest Thank you for the help! Would the upper limit for the $y$ integral be $2-x$ instead of $2$? Honestly I can't explain why I guess $2-x$, but intuitively it feels like that's the answer...

Comment: Yes. Ask yourself what is the largest possible value of $y$ given the value $x$. Answer: we have $y=2-x-z$ and the largest possible value for fixed $x$ occurs when $z=0$ because $z$ cannot be negative.

Answer (score 1):

The integral expression

$$\int_1^2 \int_0^1 \int^{3y}_y  dzdydx$$

is correct. The volume is indeed 1, which can be verified as follows. Note the cross section in the $yz$-plane is a triangle with base 2 and height 1, which gives an area 1. Then, multiple it with the thickness 1 in the $x$-direction to get the volume 1.

The second volume integral should be

$$\int_0^2 \int_0^{2-x} \int^{2-x-y}_0 dzdydx=\frac 43$$

Note that it is a cone with a right triangle base of area 2 and height 2. Thus, its volume is $\frac 13 \times 2\times 2= \frac 43$.